# php how to check if date string in between dates

Tags: php

I have date in string. i.e: 18/10/2018

and also date in an object: $pnrProduct['Date'] . i.e 20/10/2018

I would like to check if the second date is bigger then the first one (in this case it is bigger)

how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is what you need. It takes a dateable string and converts it into seconds elapsed from epoch.

In simple terms:

```
if (strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", "18/10/2018")) > strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", "20/10/2018")))
  echo "Greater";
else
  echo "Smaller";
```

Just a heads up:

```
strtotime("18-10-2018")
int(1539835200)

strtotime("20-10-2018")
int(1540008000)
```

You might need to replace the separator as:

> Dates in the *m/d/y* or *d-m-y* formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (*/*), then the American *m/d/y* is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (*-*) or a dot (*.*), then the European *d-m-y* format is assumed. If, however, the year is given in a two digit format and the separator is a dash (*-*), the date string is parsed as *y-m-d*.
>
> To avoid potential ambiguity, it's best to use ISO 8601 (*YYYY-MM-DD*) dates or [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) when possible.

Comment: @Roi Welcome...

Answer (score 0):

you must use strtotime for parse a string to date

```
$firstDate = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", "20/10/2018"));
$secondDate = strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", $pnrProduct['Date']));

if ($firstDate < $secondDate ) { /* do Something */ }
```

[For more informations](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: This won't work. Check my answer why!

Comment: ah yes thank you ! I editing my post

Answer (score 0):

How about using simply`DateTime` class?

```
<?php
$datetime1 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','18/10/2018');
$datetime2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y','20/10/2018');

if($datetime1 > $datetime2){
    echo 'datetime1 greater than datetime2';
} else {
    echo 'datetime2 greater than datetime1';
}
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/5hYBP